# No records for on kinesis stream suspending messages for 1 sec

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, amazon-kinesis, spring-cloud-aws, spring-integration-aws

I am using spring kinesis binder for consuming messages in batch mode

Some times I am not able to consume the messages from streams. This is not happening all the time

**No records for [ShardConsumer{shardOffset=KinesisShardOffset{iteratorType=AFTER_SEQUENCE_NUMBER, sequenceNumber='49594358705006691330463332232285735104253344290967650306', timestamp=null, stream='mystream-1', shard='shardId-000000000000', reset=false}, state=CONSUME}] on sequenceNumber [null]. Suspend consuming for [1000] milliseconds.**

I keep getting this message and messages are not consumed.

My Conf looks like below

```
 spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        input:
          group: mygroup
          destination: mystream-1
          content-type: application/json
        output:
          destination: mystream-2
          content-type: application/json
      kinesis:        
        bindings:
          input:
            consumer:
              listenerMode: batch
              idleBetweenPolls: 60000
              consumer-backoff: 1000
        binder:
          headers: x-item_id,x-message_type
          locks:
            table: lTLocks
            leaseDuration: 30
            refreshPeriod: 3000
          checkpoint:
            table: lTCheckPoints
```

There are messages in stream but I am not consume intermittently. Can you please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your checkpoint store and shard in the Kinesis stream contain different sequence numbers.

Please, consider to use clean up `lTCheckPoints` table before starting to consume from the stream.

I don't say that you need to do that all the time, but at least for this sake of clean testing environment.

Comment: Thank you. We noticed that some times we do not get the entry in lTCheckPoints for our group and stream at all. Is it some thing else